# Python addition of floating point numbers

Tags: python

I found something weird today (at least for me), if I add 3.14+2.74 or 3.14+2.75 on Python, it gives me an answer that is 15 digit after the decimal point.
anyone know why?

Answer (score 1):

Doing some testing this isn't limited to 2.74 and 2.75. If we try numbers like 1.5 or 8.9 we get 15 digit results.

This is probably the result of how Python handles floating-point numbers internally. Python is probably looking to give the highest precision awnser it can. So, seeing 15 digit results isn't necessarily unexpected due to this.

There's a section in the documentation that talks about how floats work more in detail: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Hope this helps.